# DIfference between using "%in%" and "==" while subsetting in R

Tags: r, subset

I was trying to extract the following using R. And both of them are giving different results. Could someone tell me the difference between using `==` and `%in%`

```
mfile1 <- subset(data3, COUNTRY_CODE_SHR__C == c("GB","IT","CA"))

mfile <- subset(data3, COUNTRY_CODE_SHR__C %in% c("GB","IT","CA"))
```

Output is as follows :

```
mfile1 - 130374 obs of 150 variable
mfile  - 392105 obs of 150 variable
```

Comment: `%in%` is used when you there multiple values to compare `==` is for checking with a single value or when vectors/matrices/dataframes are of the same length/dimensions.  You can check the help page `?"%in%"`, `?"=="`

Comment: I'm surprised you got any "obs" with the first one.

Comment: @BondedDust `data3` may have a length that is a multiple of 3